# NumPy equivalent to Keras function utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I have a Python script which uses Keras for machine learning. I am building X and Y which are features and labels respectively.

The labels are built like this:

```
def main=():

   depth = 10
   nclass = 101
   skip = True
   output = "True"
   videos = 'sensor'
   img_rows, img_cols, frames = 8, 8, depth
   channel = 1 
   fname_npz = 'dataset_{}_{}_{}.npz'.format(
    nclass, depth, skip)

   vid3d = videoto3d.Videoto3D(img_rows, img_cols, frames)
   nb_classes = nclass

   x, y = loaddata(videos, vid3d, nclass,
                    output, skip)

   X = x.reshape((x.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, frames, channel))
   Y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, nb_classes) # This needs to be changed
```

The used function "to_categorical" in Keras is explain as follows:

> to_categorical
>
> keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=None)
>
> Converts a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix.

Now I am using NumPy. May you let me know how the build the same line of code in order to work? In other words, I am looking for the equivalent of the "to_categorical" function in NumPy.

Comment: `to_categorical` is written in pure NumPy. You can just copy the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py#L9) from it.

Comment: Why don't you just go ahead and use the code from https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/utils/np_utils.py referencing its source?

Answer (score 18):

Here's one simple way to do it:

```
np.eye(nb_classes)[y]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using get_dummies.

```
>>> pd.core.reshape.get_dummies(df)
Out[30]: 
   cat_a  cat_b  cat_c
0      1      0      0
1      1      0      0
2      1      0      0
3      0      1      0
4      0      1      0
5      0      0      1
```

Comment: That looks to me like replacing one non numpy lib with another non numpy lib.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this (I don't think there is a builtin):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> n_cls, n_smp = 3, 10
>>> 
>>> y = np.random.randint(0, n_cls, (n_smp,))
>>> y
array([0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1])
>>> 
>>> res = np.zeros((y.size, n_cls), dtype=int)
>>> res[np.arange(y.size), y] = 1
>>> res
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Actually in my code "y" is the actual data, while "nbclasses" are the labels, so I assign labels to the data which is a set of *.csv files. This is prior to training a classifier. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: @Danny I'm not sure I understand 100%. You want to add columns to your data? One for each category?

Comment: I have my data ready and then I need to create X and Y. X are the features while Y are the labels of these features. I created X like this: `X = x.reshape((x.shape[0], img_rows, img_cols, frames, channel))`
Now I need to create Y - the labels of the features

Comment: @Danny I think it would be easiest if you could update your question with a small but complete example of what you have now and what you want to get.

Comment: Done. I have just updated it, I think sklearn can also be used with NumPy.

Comment: @Danny I apppreciate the effort, but that is not what I meant. I meant an example (like '[4, 0, 1, 0]') of what `y` might look like and what `Y`should look like. Anyway, I checked, what I wrote, does more or less the same as `to_categorical`; the only difference is that `to_categorical` returns floats. To get the exact same behavior, just leave out he `dtype=int` in `res = np.zeros((y.size, n_cls), dtype=int)`