# Make a model with python libraries that get a string value then return string vlaue

Tags: python, data-science

I have a table that contains two column: 
The "F1" column contains the name of people which has been written by English letters.
The "F2" column contains value equal to "F1" column which has been written by Persian letters.

Like: F1 = Ali      F2 = علی

I want to make a model with data science algorithms that has one feature (F1) and one label (F2).

When I pass an English name to this model, it predicts the equal value with Persian letter.

Like: F1 = Alex   F2 = الکس

Please notice that I don’t want the model to translate the words from English to Persian I want to it converts English letters to Persian letters.

As far as I know, the label value must be numeric but I need the predictive value to be string.

Is there any algorithm in python libraries that get a string value then return string value?

How can I create such a model into python?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can search to_categorical method. It translate strings to categorical and with this your model can understand labels. You can check [NumPy equivalent to Keras function utils.to_categorical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684379/numpy-equivalent-to-keras-function-utils-to-categorical)

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts:

1. A neural network is one type of machine learning model that could be suitable here.
2. It is common to convert strings into numbers or arrays of numbers that can be used in machine learning and then back again, for example using [one-hot encoding](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

I would transform the strings into one-hot encodings and feed that into a neural network. There are many Python libraries you could use for this, but [Scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html) or [Keras](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/) could be a good starting place!